# Testing PWAs on iOS

Tags: deployment, localhost, progressive-web-apps

I'm reading an [article](https://dev.to/haideralipunjabi/testing-pwas-on-mobile-devices-during-development-22mm) that talks about how you can test your PWA on an Android device using ADP (Android Debug Bridge). As I understand it, it means it's possible to debug your PWA in real time on Android devices. Is there any alternative for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes using safari and activating the developer mode in your iPhone, you can access the full PWA console and other advanced panel of the PWA running on the device. So you can see network request, service workers and so on.

That works pretty well!